# Computability -- prove the program does or does not exist

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, computability

I know that we can prove a program is uncountable by basing it off the halting program, which does not exist. To clarify, we can use the theorem

[image]

> The Halting Problem is uncomputable; i.e., there does not exist a
> computer program TestHalt with the behavior specified above on all
> inputs (P, x).

But I don't really get how to put it into practice.

How would you say a program P(F, x, y) that returns true if the program F outputs y when given x as input (i.e. F(x) = y) and false otherwise can't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose such program $P$ existed, but change it a little to output "yes" or "no" instead of true and false. Let $G$ be the program that outputs 1 on **any** input, and for any program $F$, let $F_1 = G\circ F$. Then $F_1$ is computable, so the function $H(x) =  P(F_1, x, 1)$ is also computable. But this function is exactly $\text{TestHalt}(F,x)$, a contradiction.